# postgress: insert rows to table with multiple records from other join tables

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-insert

ّ am trying to insert multiple records got from the join table to another table `user_to_property`. In the `user_to_property` table `user_to_property_id` is primary, not null it is not autoincrementing. So I am trying to add `user_to_property_id` manually by an increment of 1.

```sql
WITH selectedData  AS 
    (   -- selection of the data that needs to be inserted
            SELECT t2.user_id as userId
FROM property_lines t1
INNER JOIN user t2 ON t1.account_id = t2.account_id
    )
INSERT INTO user_to_property (user_to_property_id, user_id, property_id, created_date)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX( user_to_property_id )+1 FROM user_to_property),(SELECT 
        selectedData.userId
        FROM selectedData),3,now());
```

The above query gives me the below error:

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

How to insert multiple records to a table from the join of other tables? where the `user_to_property` table contains a unique record for the same `user-id` and `property_id` there should be only 1 record.

Comment: The problem you are facing comes from the subquery (SELECT selectedData.userId FROM SelectedData) of the VALUES clause.
Try to restrict the result of this subquery to one row at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for Insert you use either `values` or `select`. The structure `values( select...)` often (generally?) just causes more trouble than it worth, and it is never necessary. You can always select a constant or an expression. In this case convert to just select. For generating your ID get the max value from your table and then just add the row_number that you are inserting: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4398e299cf66af19e658935bb57b0034))

```
insert into user_to_property(user_to_property_id  
                            , user_id  
                            , property_id   
                            , created 
                            ) 
with start_with(current_max_id) as 
    ( select max(user_to_property_id) from user_to_property )
select current_max_id + id_incr, user_id, 3, now()  
  from (
        select t2.user_id, row_number() over() id_incr
          from property_lines t1
          join users t2 on t1.account_id = t2.account_id
       ) js
  join start_with on true;
```

**A couple notes:**

1. DO NOT use `user` for table name, or any other object name. It is a
   documented reserved word by both Postgres and SQL standard (and has
   been since Postgres v7.1 and the SQL 92 Standard at lest).
2. You really should create another column or change the column type
   `user_to_property_id` to auto-generated. Using Max()+1, or
   anything based on that idea, is a *virtual guarantee* you will generate
   duplicate keys. Much to the amusement of users and developers alike.
   What happens in an MVCC when 2 users run the query concurrently.

Comment: In user_to_property table for user_id with property_id already exist another records or duplicate record should not be inserted.

Comment: See the [on conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html) clause of the insert statement. It will be something like `on conflict (user_id, property_id) do nothing`.